# PostAndAsyncReply deadlock on exception

Tags: .net, f#

Given 2 agents, that communicates by sending messages:

> Agent 1 sends a `PostAndAsyncReply` to agent 2, waiting for the result.
>
> Agent 2 starts processing the message, but throws an exception.

Now Agent 1 is deadlocked, since no reply is ever sent from Agent 1. As I see it, there is 2 ways to handle such a scenario:

1. I could set a `timeout` for `PostAndAsyncReply`, but since the operation could be long running, the time it takes to execute differs.
2. Wrap the code in Agent 2 in a `try..catch`, and then reply with some value that indicates an error. However, that would mean all the code that handles messages with a ReplyChannel, needs to be wrapped inside a `try..catch`, which seems.. cumbersome.

How would one go around handling such a scenario?

Comment: `try ... finally` block wrapping the operation wouldn't be *that* bad, IMO...

Comment: If the operation is long-running, it sounds like a bad idea to wait for a result. Would it be possible to send an asynchronous message to kick off the operation, and then, when it completes, let it send another message which can be picked up by a third agent?

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a higher-order function that somewhat alleviates the `try...catch`:

```
let replyOrFail (chan: AsyncReplyChannel<option<'T>>) (action: Async<'T>) : Async<unit> =
    async {
        try
            let! reply = action
            return chan.Reply (Some reply)
        with _ ->
            return chan.Reply None
    }

let agent2 =
    (* declare mailbox... *)
    (* matching received message: *)
    | MessageFromAgent1 chan ->
        do! replyOrFail chan <| async {
            return! longComputationThatMightThrow()
        }
    (* ... *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention that exception is not the only case for lack of response from `Agent`. Another reason might be that `Agent` has simply terminated for some natural reason, but his partners are not aware.

Hence, IMHO, a lack of response is a natural thing with agents, and recievers must be ready to handle it. So, I just want to inform them properly on this matter. And I did it as follows:

1. I made some estimations on operations length, and used `PostAndTryAsyncReply` with these estimates
2. In case of timeout I gave a special case of return: `NotResponding`. In this case agent can decide what to do.

Here's an example:

```
// outside of the agent
type Timeouts = {
    load : int
    connect : int
    agent : int
    awaiter : int
}

let timeouts = { load = 5000; connect = 2000; agent = 1000; awaiter = 100 }

// a static member in a class that wraps my agent
let tryCommand command timeout = async {
    let! answer = a.PostAndTryAsyncReply (command, timeout)
    match answer with
    | Some state -> return State state
    | None -> return NotResponding
}        

// regular members of the wrapper
member x.Connect () = tryCommand Commands.Connect (timeouts.connect + timeouts.agent)
member x.Reload () = tryCommand Commands.Reload (timeouts.load + timeouts.agent)
member x.Close () = tryCommand Commands.Close timeouts.agent
```

Please note that you can extend this approach further, for example:

1. Give the operations a chance to estimate their expected execution time
2. Keep better track of agent's states and give more detailed responses

**PS**. This idea was not yet tested but looks promising:

All agents have similar pattern:

```
let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec initialState () = 
        async {
        }
    and anotherState () = 
        async {
        }
    // and so on

    initialState () // simply run it
```

We can try to write it like that:

```
let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec initialState () = 
        async {
        }
    and anotherState () = 
        async {
        }
    and errorState e = 
        async {
             // informing on error
        }
    // and so on

    async { // instead of just initialState ()
        let! res = initialState () |> Async.Catch
        match res with
        | Choice2Of2 e -> return! errorState ()
        | _ -> return ()
    }
```

So, here I insert additional error handling inside agent initialization so that to be able to inform users that agent's down.